# Is there any specific reason to add Descending iterator only in Linked list and not in arrayList?

Tags: java

Using List Iterator I can traverse in descending order with previous(). While this being the case, what advantage does Descending Iterator gives me? If it is just for convenience, then why it is not present in arrayList ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `descendingIterator()` methods comes from the interface `Deque`, which the ArrayList doesn't implement.

It allows you to traverse the list in the `descendingOrder` `(last (tail) to first (head))`